# Error: This template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual studio 2015 and I'm trying to create a test application for Windows Phone 8.1. When I create a new project, I get this message:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same error. Any solutions to this?

Comment: @Nick What operating system are you on? I am Windows 7 SP1 64 bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. Open Visual Studio and go to `Tools` > `Extensions and Updates`
2. Uninstall "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015"
3. Restart Visual Studio 2015
4. Open Visual Studio and to `Tools` > `Extensions and Updates` again
5. Install "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015"
6. Restart Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar error message when trying to create an MVC Web App on VS2015. Found [this](http://www.itorian.com/2012/08/error-this-template-attempted-to-load.html) solution and it worked for me.

1. Go to Tools>Extensions and Updates
2. Search the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015
3. Install NuGet Package Manager
4. Restart VS2015

Hope it helps.

Comment: It solved my problem. I was downgrading from VS 2017 to VS 2015 and completely forgot about deleted NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

On VS2017 go to **"Tools-> Extension and Updates"** then find and Check "Xamarin for Visual Studio", it was disable, i enabled it, and restarted. Worked for me.

Refer:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/83460/cannot-create-a-new-xamarin-project-using-vs2017.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to tools>Extensions and updates
2. Search for Visual studio tools for Apache cordova and enable it.
3. Restart visual studio and it will work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
1) go to installation path for VS2015 from command prompt and type:
`devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates`
2) 
- Go to Tools>Extensions and Updates
- Search the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015
- Install NuGet Package Manager
- Restart Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

Another way on VS2017 (and probably VS2019), open the **Visual Studio Installer** (from the Start menu), and when it loads up, press **modify**. From there, click on the tab at the top to select individual packages and in the list select `NuGet Package Manager`. Then press **modify** at the bottom-right to apply the change.