# Xamarin.Forms.VsTemplate issue coming when creating app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Getting issue with Xamarin.forms.VsTemplate. Anybody know how to resolve this?[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656261/error-this-template-attempted-to-load-component-assembly-microsoft-visualstudi did you try anything similar to this..? Its to do with the nuget package manager. Uninstall and install it again.

Comment: I already tried that way and even posted to xamarin forums. they are saying there is something bad with VS Installation.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue. Reinstalling Xamarin didn't help. It turns out there were two versions of the Xamarin extension installed at the same time and Visual Studio apparently loads the older one instead of the newer.

Go to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\` and remove the folder of the older version. Make sure only the most recent version remains.

If you've fiddled around too much, you may want to uninstall Xamarin from Windows' Programs & Features and reinstall Xamarin using the Visual Studio installer (modify => re-check Xamarin).

(By the way, this also fixed the problem where I would not get the new "Cross-Platform" project templates.)